# How prove this limit via epsilon delta?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (4,1)}{\frac{y}{2x-y}}=\frac{1}{7}$$

I know so far that $|x-4|<\delta\quad \&\quad |y-1|<\delta$, and that I can use

$$\bigg|\frac{y-1}{2x-y} + \frac{1}{2x-y} - \frac{1}{7}\bigg|$$ and I get one delta, but how to continue from here, or is it even correct?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify we can change coordinates $u=x-4$ and $v=y-1$ such that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (4,1)}{\frac{y}{2x-y}}=\lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)}{\frac{v+1}{2u-v+7}}=\frac{1}{7}$$

and assuming wlog $|u|,|v|\le 1$

$$\left|\frac{y-1}{2x-y}  - \frac{1}{7}\right|=\left|\frac{v+1}{2u-v+7}  - \frac{1}{7}\right|=\left|\frac{8v-2u}{7(2u-v+7)}\right|\le$$

$$\le\frac87\left|\frac{v}{2u-v+7}\right|+\frac27\left|\frac{u}{2u-v+7}\right|\le$$

$$\le \frac87\left|\frac{v}{4}\right|+\frac27\left|\frac{u}{4}\right| \le \frac87\frac{\delta}{4}+\frac27\frac{\delta}{4}=\frac{5}{14} \delta$$

Comment: You calculated the limit in $(-4,-1)$. Also the $10$ in denominator is wrong!.

Comment: @zwim Opsss yes of course, I fix that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I invariably give the same advice for these situations, it is easier to work in $(0,0)$ because it triggers more reflexes.

So set $\begin{cases}x=4+u & u\to 0\\y=1+v & v\to 0\end{cases}$

Note that you can as well have $|u|<\delta$ and $|v|<\delta$.

Then evaluate $f(x,y)-\frac 17=\dfrac{Num(u,v)}{Den(u,v)}$

Notice that $N(u,v)\to 0$ and $Den(u,v)\to cst\neq 0$

What you want to do is proving $|Num(u,v)|<n\delta$ for some $n$, use triangular inequality and $\delta<\epsilon$

And for denominator $|Den(u,v)>k|$ for that use $\delta<1$ then $|7+2u-v|>7-2-1=4$

Conclude by taking $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon)$ so that both parts are verified.